# How to add footnote right below the author's name in LaTex?

Tags: footnotes

I have this code: How can I align the affiliations directly below the author's names in a footnote format? Like the following picture[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\title{Title\footnote{We thank...}}
\author{%
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
Bob\footnotemark[1] , %
Sheldon\footnotemark[2]
\footnotemark[3]
\footnotemark[4]%
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\thanks{ Corresponding author. \newline
\hspace*{2em}E-mail addresses: emails...} , %
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
Nate\footnotemark[5]
}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent\footnotetext[1]{Uni 1}\\
\footnotetext[2]{Uni 2}\\
\footnotetext[3]{Uni 3}\\
\footnotetext[4]{Uni 4}\\
\footnotetext[5]{Uni 5}\\

\begin{abstract}
    Text
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you adding that information as footnotes when they are not footnotes? Maybe the `authblk` package is something you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the `\maketitle` command inside a `minipage` environment. And manually switch the `mpfootnote` mark at correct locations.

By the way, the format commands `\noindent` and `\\` was not useful for `\footnotetext`. Using `\footnotetext` the contents will be typed in the footnote location and the format was already defined. By doing this, you only create multiple empty lines in your document. I have deleted them.

If you want some space between the title part and abstract part, you could use `\vspace{some length}` between `end{minipage}` and `begin{abstract}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\title{Title\footnote{We thank...}}
\author{%
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
Bob\footnotemark[1] , %
Sheldon\footnotemark[2]
\footnotemark[3]
\footnotemark[4]%
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\thanks{ Corresponding author. \newline
\hspace*{2em}E-mail addresses: emails...} , %
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
Nate\footnotemark[5]
}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}%
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\alph{mpfootnote}}\footnotetext[1]{Uni 1}
\footnotetext[2]{Uni 2}
\footnotetext[3]{Uni 3}
\footnotetext[4]{Uni 4}
\footnotetext[5]{Uni 5}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{3cm} % <--- add some space
\begin{abstract}
Text
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]